# Pthread using pthread_cond_wait inside signal handle blocked

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I want to write a program which can stop (hang up) all other pthreads without main thread, I use `pthread_kill` to send a signal to the target thread to call its signal handler, which can block itself. But I got stuck. Here's the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t _mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void cur_thread_wait(int sig)
{
    cout << pthread_self() << endl;

//  pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &_mutex);  
//  pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
}

void signal_all()
{
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
}

void *print(void *)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
        cout << dec << i << endl;
    }
    return nullptr;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, nullptr);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, nullptr);

    signal(SIGUSR1, cur_thread_wait);

    pthread_t pid1, pid2, pid3;
    pthread_create(&pid1, nullptr, print, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&pid2, nullptr, print, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&pid3, nullptr, print, nullptr);

//  usleep(400);

    pthread_kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_kill(pid2, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_kill(pid3, SIGUSR1);

    signal_all();


    pthread_exit(nullptr);
}
```

In fact, I think there is really no need to create a `mutex` (is this true?)... I'm a newbie on linux programming. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is broken - you should NEVER block in a signal handler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do* need to lock the mutex before calling `pthread_cond_wait`; it expects it to be locked, it unlocks it, waits for the condition variable to be asserted, and then re-locks it before returning to you.

From `pthread_cond_wait(3p)`:

```c
int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *restrict cond,
    pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex);
```

> The `pthread_cond_timedwait()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` functions shall block  on a condition variable. The application shall ensure that these functions are called with *mutex* locked by the  calling  thread; otherwise,  an  error (for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and robust mutexes) or undefined behavior (for other mutexes) results.

Comment: Thanks. I find my fault... if I put `usleep` just before `signal_all`, the program goes right. Besides you're right because `mutex` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  You could also use `sched_yield` on most systems (including Linux).

Comment: He should not make blocking calls in a signal handler. Also, since question is marked C++, killing and canceling posix threads can cause problems in C++. See e.g. https://skaark.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/pthread_cancel-considered-harmful/